# Switch back to PowerShell mode after switching to cmd mode

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, windows-8.1

From PowerShell, we can run `cmd` to switch to a command prompt. From there, how can we switch back to PowerShell. For instance...

```
PS> cmd
C:\temp> echo I am in command mode.
I am in command mode.

C:\temp> echo How do I switch back to PowerShell mode?
How do I switch back to PowerShell mode?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type `exit`.

```
PS C:\Scripts> cmd
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Scripts>exit
PS C:\Scripts>
```